# VSCode Extension Manifest - values with % symbol

Tags: visual-studio-code, manifest, package.json, vscode-extensions

I just started building my own VSCode extension and found some examples for the `package.json` manifest where values are surrounded by percentage `%` symbols like this:

`"description": "%config.alwaysSignOff%"`

I can‘t find any explanation of what this means or what it is good for. Could one explain the purpose of this symbol? Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: can it be i18n (translation), is there a `package.nls.json` file

Comment: Oh yes...there are a few nls files. So it’s for translation purposes?